# How to associate a progress bar with a button in Xamarin with Visual studio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to the Xamarin world, so I'm in a real need of your help. In my very first application I want to associate a progress bar with a button. So that when I click the button the progress bar starts and when the progress ends the progress bar disappears.

Here is my C# code:

```
translateButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    ProgressBar pb = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    pb.Enabled = true;

    translateNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translateNumber))
    {
         callButton.Text = "Call";
         callButton.Enabled = false;
         pb.Enabled = true;
    }

    else
    {
        callButton.Text = "Call" + translateNumber;
        callButton.Enabled = true;
        pb.Enabled = true;
    }
};
```

this code from this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/) on Xamarin website.

Comment: "associate a progress bar with a button", that makes no sense, also you didn't asked about any problem, code something and when you have a problem ask about it.

Comment: Why no sense! simply rise the progress bar until the process that the button run terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
ProgressBar pb;
Button translateButton;
EditText phoneNumberText;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.translateButton);
    phoneNumberText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.phoneNumberText);
    pb = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.pb);
    pb.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

    translateButton.Click += translateButtonClicked;
}

async void translateButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pb.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    await myMethod();
    pb.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}

async Task myMethod()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        //
        // Do the work stuff here
        //
    });
}
```